# Sign a pdf document using signature from USB token in python

Tags: python, tkinter, smartcard, pyscard

I have a requirement where i need to sign one of multiple pdf's usig the signature from USB token. I want to create a desktop tool using python, where user can select the source path and export path for pdf's and can even insert his PIN to access USB token signature.

So far i have gathered information as for Desktop tool i will use **"tkinter"** module which i have already worked on.

For USB token signature read, i was searching module used for python and came across **"smartcard"** and **"pyscard"**, but didn't find much about these modules.

Can some one help me with more information on how i can use the signature from USB token and add on pdf files using python.

Comment: I am not able to verify load the signature from the USB token, do you know any other module except pkcs11